# Semicolon in url as a separator for query strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep hearing that W3C recommends to use ";" instead of "&" as a query string separator.

> We recommend that HTTP server implementors, and in particular, CGI
>   implementors support the use of ";" in place of "&" to save authors
>   the trouble of escaping "&" characters in this manner.

Can somebody please explain why ";" is recommended instead of "&"?

Also, i tried using `";"` instead of `"&"`. (example: `.com?str1=val1;str2=val2` ) . When reading as `Request.QueryString["str1"]` i get "`val1;str2=val2`". So if `";"` is recommended, how do we read the query strings?

Comment: Do you have a source for that quote?

Comment: [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2) after a [very brief Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=%22CGI+implementors+support+the+use+of%22).

Comment: I think it's not so much instead of. But as well as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the linked document says, `;` is recommended over `&` because

> the use of the "&" character to separate form fields interacts with its use in SGML attribute values to delimit character entity references.

For example, say you want your URL to be `...?q1=v1&q2=v2`

There's nothing wrong with `&` *there*. But if you want to put that query into an HTML attribute, `<a href="...?q1=v1&q2=v2">`, it *breaks* because, inside an HTML attribute, `&` represents the start of a character entity. You have to escape the `&` as `&amp;`, giving `<a href="...?q1=v1&amp;q2=v2">`, and it'd be easier if you didn't have to.

`;` isn't overloaded like this at all; you can put one in an HTML attribute and not worry about it. Thus it'd be much simpler if servers recognised `;` as a query parameter separator.

However, by the look of things (based on your experiment), ASP.Net *doesn't* recognise it as such. How to get it to? I'm not sure you can.

Comment: Thank you Rawling. I just tried <a href="...?q1=v1&q2=v2"> click here </a>, in an html and it works. May be, the specification is old. Or ASP.net makes "&" work however you give it and makes ";" useless in this case... :P

Comment: You can get most web servers to recognize ; using URL rewriting

Comment: It works in html, because the parsers are so crazy tolerant, but not in xhtml

Answer (score 1):

In short, HTML is a big mess (due to its leniency), and using semicolons help to simplify this a LOT.

In order to use semicolons as the separator, i don't know if .NET allows this customization or whether we developers need to write our own methods to process the QueryString. .NET does give us access to the raw QueryString, and we can run with it from there. This is what i did. I wrote my own methods, which wasn't too hard, but it took a lot of testing time and debugging, some of which was Microsoft's fault for not even conforming to web standards when dealing with surrogate pairs. I made sure my implementation works with the full range of Unicode characters including the Multilingual plane (thus for Chinese and Japanese characters, etc.).

Before adding my own findings, I want also confirm and include the great info that Rawling, Jeevan, and BeniBela have pointed out in Rowling's answer and their comments to such answer: it is incorrect in HTML to not escape them, but it usually works, but only because parsers are so tolerant. With that, i also explain why this can lead to bugs with such improper encoding (which probably most developers fall victim to).

One cannot depend on this leniency of improperly encoding ampersands in QueryStrings, and sometimes this leniency leads to nasty bugs. Let's say for instance a QueryString passes a random ASCII string (or user input) and they are not properly encoded. Then 'amp;' which follows '&' gets decoded and the unexpected consequence is that 'amp;' is essentially 'swallowed'. (By swallowed, i mean it gets 'eaten' or it goes missing.) A practical usage scenario is when the user is asked for input that goes into a database and the user inputs HTML (like here at StackOverflow) but because it is not posted correctly then nasty bugs develop.

The real advantage of the ';' separator is in simplicity: proper encoding of ampersand separated QueryStrings takes two steps of complication for URL strings in an HTML page (and in XML too). First keys and values shud be URL encoded and then all concatenated, and then the whole QueryString or URL shud be HTML encoded (or for XML, encoded with a very similar encoding to HTML encoding). Also don't forget that the encoding process for HTML encoding and URL encoding are different, and it's important that they are different. A developer needs to be careful between the two. And since they are similar, it's not uncommon to see them mixed up by novice programmers.

A good example of a potential problematic URL is when passing two name/values in a QueryString:

- a = 'me & you', and
- b = 'you & me'.

Here, using '&' as a separator, then '?a=me+%26+you&b=you+%26+me' is a proper querystring BUT it shud also be HTML encoded before being written to HTML source code. This is important to be bug free. Most developers aren't careful to do this two step process of first URL Encoding the keys and values and then HTML encoding the full URL in the HTML source. It's no wonder why, when i had to sit down and seriously think this process thru and test out my conclusions thoroughly. Imaging when the name value is 'year=año' or far more complex when we need Chinese or Japanese characters that use surrogate pairs to represent them!

For the same above key value pairs for a and b, when using ';' as the separator, the process is MUCH simpler. As a matter of fact, the ampersand separator makes the process more than twice as complex as using the semicolon separator! Here's the same info represented using the ';' as a separator: '?a=me+%26+you;b=you+%26+me'. We notice that the only difference tho is that there's no '&' in the string. But using this ';' separator means that no second process of HTML encoding the URL or QueryString is needed. Now imagine if i were writing HTML and wanted correct HTML and needed to write the HTML to explain all this! All this HTML encoding with '&' really adds a lot of complication (and for many developers, quite a lot of confusion too).

Novice developers wud simply not HTML encode the QueryString or URL, which is CORRECT when ; is the separator. But it leaves room for bugs when ampersand is improperly encoded. So '?someText=blah&amp;blah' wud *need* proper encoding.

Also in .NET, we can write XML documentation for our methods. Well, just today, i wrote a little explanation that used the above 'a=me+%26+you&b=you+%26+me' example. And in my XML, i had to manually type all those &amp; character entities for the XML. In XML documentation, it's picky so one must correctly encode ampersands. But the leniency in HTML adds to ambiguity.

Perhaps this wasn't too confusing. But all the confusion or difficulty is due to using a character which shud be HTML encoded as the separator, thus '&' is the culprit. And semicolon relieves all that complication.

One last consideration: with how much more complicated the '&' separator makes this process, it's no wonder to me why the Microsoft implementation of surrogate pairs in QueryStrings still does not follow the official specifications. And if you write your own methods, you MUST account for Microsoft's incorrect use of percent-encoding surrogate pairs. The official specs forbid percent-encoding of surrogate pairs in UTF-8. So anyone who writes their own methods which also handle the full range of Unicode characters, beware of this.