# How to route a request that has a semicolon in the URI

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to build a proxy that will accept requests from existing clients  that send POST requests with a semicolon in the URI.  The original clients passes both a session ID and and Client ID as in the following example.

Example URL:
https://myappdomain.com/api/updateData;jsessionid=xxxx?clientId=yyyy

I actually don't care what the those values are.  My main problem is that I can't figure out how to get the web-api to route the request.  If I replace the semicolon with a question mark (?) or move the ";jsessionid=xxxx" to the end of the URL after the "?clientId", it works just fine.  However I can't get this to work if the ";jsessionid=xxxx" immediately follows the method name.

I have tried a number of things to see if I can keep the original URI but I always get a 404 Not Found error.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UpdateDataController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] CustomClass value)
    {
        return Ok("OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: If nothing else, I think you can use URL rewriting to work around it. Someone else will probably come up with a better answer though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing

Comment: Also, this may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940981/semicolon-in-url-as-a-separator-for-query-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into your `Startup.Configure` method right before the `UseRouting`, `UseRouter`, or `UseMvc` calling.

```
app.Use(next => http =>
{
    http.Request.Path = new PathString(http.Request.Path.Value.Replace(';', '?'));
    return next(http);
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am working inside of an AWS Lambda function for dotnet core and it is  giving me this coding error "
Error CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type pmtsave-service C:\git\Sysco\pmtsave-service\src\pmtsave-service\Startup.cs"  This is on the "http" part of the first line 'code' app.Use(next => http =>"

Comment: Got the change to compile by adding "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;"  This is an AWS Lambda function that I am testing locally as a console app.  This doesn't appear to work yet.  The following request works http://localhost:15737/api/values?aa=bbb  however this does not http://localhost:15737/api/values;aa=bbb

Comment: You need make sure this is added before the ASP.NET Core MVC handles the request. Btw, I have no idea what your "AWS lambda function" means, and this code should be inside a the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method of your `Startup` class as a solution for a standard ASP.NET Core project.

Comment: I am using AWS (Amazon Web Services) to build serverless solutions.  For small projects, I can usually stay within their free tier.  [AWS Lambda dotnet](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer/README.md) .  I have this just before the app.UseMvc(); command.  I will keep trying.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The solution does work for other characters.  For example, I added a function to echo back a number from the url http://localhost:15737/api/values/1.  I changed it to replace the number 1 with 2 and that works fine.  It just doesn't work for the semi-colon.

Comment: Problem appears to be with the question mark (?).  For example, I can change the ; to / and routing works just fine.  However if I try to change the ? to something else, it doesn't work.  Will see if I can find a creative solution (i.e. not change to a ?) to see if I can get the routing to work.

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to @Alsein for pointing me in the right direction.  Trying to change the path to a question mark (?) gave me problems.  I also found that the parameters after the (?) where not part of the http.Request.Path.  Because I didn't need the ;jsessionid in the original request and the parameters after the (?) were not part of the original http.Request.Path, I just stripped out everything past the semi-colon (;)

```
app.Use(next => http =>
{
    if (http.Request.Path.Value.Contains(';'))
    {
        http.Request.Path = new PathString(http.Request.Path.Value.Substring(0, http.Request.Path.Value.IndexOf(';')));
    }
    return next(http);
});
```